# How to change single values in dataframe when condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From what I know, my current approach to change values in a pandas dataframe is far from optimal and is really hurting my workflow.

Example:
I want to check if a name is found inside another dataframe and if so put in values from this dataframe using `iloc` of the searched name from the first dataframe:

```
for idx in id_list_of_names:    
    name = df["name"].iloc[idx]      
    if name in df_two["name"].values:
        df["value"].iloc[idx] = df_two["value"][df_two["name"]==name].values
```

Dataframe 1, `df`:

```
id | name | value
1  | "David" | 0
2  | "Lisa"  | 0 
...............
```

Dataframe 2, `df_two`:

```
id | name | value
1  | "Kevin" | 10
.................
255  | "David"  | 22  
.................
```

What I want to do is put the value from `df_two` for David (`value = 22`) in Dataframe 1 at the `iloc` of David (`df["value"].iloc[1] == 22`). This should happen for all the names from `df` if the respective name exists in `df_two`.

`merge()` is my usual solution to this, but since the column `value` already exists a new column `value_1` would be created if I use `merge` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you merge your 2 dataframes on Name, and then apply a custom function to create a column `final_value` which chooses between `value` and `value_1` ?

Comment: This is another approach I was using. I thought there is some nifty way to skip the step where you create an additional column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge` to merge the two dataframes together keeping `df` as the main dataframe (left merge). As you noted, since the column names are the same these be given new names (adding an `_x` and `_y` suffix).

First drop the `id` column from `df_two` and then merge:

```
df_two = df_two.drop('id', axis=1)
df = df.merge(df_two, on='name', how='left')
```

Now, create a new column `value` by using `value_y` when there is a value available, otherwise `value_x`:

```
df['value'] = df['value_y'].fillna(df['value_x'])
```

Last, drop the unwanted columns:

```
df = df.drop(['value_x', 'value_y'], axis=1)
```